# Looking for possible strategies for avoiding applet reloads

Tags: java, applet

I've implemented an interactive map applet, which is embedded in a web application. The application uses some Ajax, but has a predominantly page based structure.
The problem is, navigating away from and back to the page containing the applet causes an applet reload, which takes several seconds.
Possible ways to alleviate this problem I thought of are:-

- Make the applet run continuously in a separate browser window (I lose integration with the main web app though)
- Convert the web app to use Ajax exclusively to avoid page reloads
- Implement the map view as a standalone desktop app

If there is some way of preventing applet reloads in the browser I would be very interested to hear about it, but I don't think this is possible due to the applet lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you enumerated all options, their advantages and disadvantages. 
I'd like to suggest you a combination of options you suggested.

You can separate you applet into 2 components. First, heavy-weight application that will be started using a java web start. It will contain all application logic and will run in minimized (or even transparent) window. It will prepare image and send it via network to light-weight applet that just shows it.

I this case you do not loose your application integrity: map is shown in browser. The applet is very light weight, so it starts fast. The stand-alone app implements the most of programming logic.

Here is how to make window transparent: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/